# DeviceNetworkInformation: Which is which?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to check whether any internet connection is available - i.e can I start webrequests expected to succeed.

**IsCellularDataEnabled** - is this true if there's GPRS/3G/etc available?
**IsNetworkAvailble** - is this true if VOICE CALLS are possible, or does this too have something to do with the internet?
**IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled** - Should I be concerned with this at all? (I know what Data Roaming is...)
**IsWifiAvailable** - If this false,I can still get internet from 3G.

So what I'm looking for is:

```
if (/*something*/){ //you can use the internet
}
```

thanks

(EDIT: I don't have a device readily available, otherwise I'd just try it out :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IsNetworkAvailable** is true, if there is some kind of data connection available, no matter which (GPRS, 3G, Roaming, WiFi or via USB cable).

**IsCellularDataEnabled** is true if the phone is connected via a mobile data connection. It doesn't give you any status about Voice calls but only data.

**IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled**: The user is connected via a mobile data connection via a 3rd provider (roaming). You should only use a minimal amount of traffic because roaming data is often expensive for the user. (Because of that you can check this status)

**IsWifiAvailable** is true if you are connected via WiFi. If false there may be a mobile data connection via 3G and so on.

So, if you only want to know IF there is some kind of connection you can use **IsNetworkAvailable** - all other states are only giving you more detailed information about what kind of connection there is.

Answer (score 2):

Only

> if(NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) {
>
> }

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx

Comment: If there is a GSM network, but no internet (GPRS, 3G, Wifi) this will be false?

Comment: Yes. No internet (wifi, 3G,...) => false

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a chance to test it on Monday, I'll accept it then.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is not possible situation when you haven't Internet connection and `GetIsNetworkAvailable()` is `true`

Comment: @Ku6opr : I tested, it works very well. There is a connection if WiFi, cellular data or usb are enabled. If nothing is enabled (so just the GSM network is active): false

Comment: I mean in bad data connection environment with unexpected connection drops

Comment: Also: I've read that Best Practice suggests `DeviceNetworkInterface` instead of `NetworkInterface`. Is the `IsNetworkAvailable` property the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains a false assumption.

You want to know if there's a connection so your request is likely to succeed.  Only the oppostie can be true though. You can only know that if there's no connection a request will definitely fail.

There are lots of reasons that it may not be possible to make a successful web request even if there's a connection to an external network available.

You **MUST** code to handle a request failing even if there is a connection.

Things that can stop a request from being successful even if there is a connection:

- proxy servers or firewalls blocking the request
- being connected to a local network which doesn't have access to the destination server
- a slow network connection causing the request to timeout
- the destination server being down/offline/unavailable
- an error on the server
- etc. ...

Comment: Okay, my question wasn't well worded than. I'm not looking to replace error handlers with a simple if. I just want to know when I shouldn't even ATTEMPT online mode.